# parse multilevel json in php

Tags: php, json

I am receiving a multilevel json like this:

```
{"id":"3",
"field2":"ssss",
"field3":[
         {"field31":"wwwww",
         "field32":"qqqq"},
         {"field31":"wwwww",
         "field32":"qqqq"},
         {"field31":"wwwww",
         "field32":"qqqq"},
   ]}
```

I am reading json values (first level) like this in php:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_post = json_decode(utf8_decode($json), true);
$id = $json_post['id'];
```

But I don't know how to get the json in the second level. What is the simplest way? I just need to get the json in other variable like $json_post, I will read it in a for bucle to get each row of the json file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's going to give you a PHP object if you run `json_decode(utf8_decode($json));`

```
echo $json_post->field3->field31;
```

EDIT: I missed that you were using the conversion to array. This is what the array would look like

```
    echo $json_post['field3']['field31'];
```

Comment: Not when the second parameter is set to true. Then the result in an array.

Comment: All my parameters are strings. Can I use that?

Comment: @JohnConde Good point. Missed that and have amended.

Comment: It works. I will accept when the timer allows me. Thanks

Comment: One question, how can I check if the second level is empty?

Comment: You can either use `isset()` or run a `foreach`